# Graphicsmagick file permissions on uploaded files in Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu-12.04, graphicsmagick

I'm having some trouble with Graphicsmagick (GM) not having permissions, on my Ubuntu 12.04 server, to change images uploaded from my node app.

I've changed the folder permissions where it gets uploaded to 777 (drwxrwxrwx) (just as an experiment, for now), but the files that are uploaded gets 664 (-rw-rw-r--).

The image is uploaded to `/uploads/temp/`, gets moved and resized with GM to `/uploads/public/project1/thumbs`

The project1 folder is created by the node app and will have 775 (drwxrwxr-x) permissions...

So, clearly not understanding how folder permissions work in Linux I turn to Stack to see if someone can shed some light on the matter.

How can I make GM have the permission to change the images? Can I put GM in a user group with higher permissions or how would I go by this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `777` permissions are helpful, but find a tutorial/article on the web about `umask` . The `umask` for the user/ower of files that are being written needs to be adjusted. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to change umask to 000 for the user running the node-process (using forever) but it doesn't change the permissions on the files and folders created by node, but it does change for files created by for example using the touch command in shell... I even tried to run node as root but still nothing. Any ideas? Do I have to set the permissions in the app itself?

Comment: I just fixed this exact same problem for my project. The uploaded image is allowed to have 664 as the permission. Your problem is likely that your path is wrong. If you can't find what is wrong with the path, try switching the path separators from ``\`` to ``/``

Comment: It's embarrassing but you are correct. The path to the file had changed so GM couldn't find it.

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed this exact same problem for my project. The uploaded image is allowed to have 664 as the permission. Your problem is likely that your path is wrong. If you can't find what is wrong with the path, try switching the path separators from `\` to `/`
                    – TFischer

It's embarrassing but you are correct. The path to the file had changed so GM couldn't find it. – mottosson